# String Interpolation Convert to a Type

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I'm creating an s3 bucket using AWS CDK and i'm trying to usse string interpolation for the removal policy.

```
object_storage_bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self,
            "object-storage-bucket",
            removal_policy=f"RemovalPolicy.{props.s3_removal_policy}",
            auto_delete_objects=True,
            object_ownership=s3.ObjectOwnership.BUCKET_OWNER_ENFORCED,
            bucket_name=f"{props.customer}-{props.region}-object-storage",
        )
```

But when i run the code, i'd get this error `TypeError: type of argument removal_policy must be one of (aws_cdk.RemovalPolicy, NoneType); got str instead`

I know i can do `removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` and it will work, but i'm trying to pass `DESTROY` or `RETAIN` from a yaml file

```
customer: taylor swift
region: us-west-2
s3_removal_policy: DESTROY
```

how do i do that?

Comment: Perhaps `getattr(RemovalPolicy, props.s3_removal_policy)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value into the enum for it to resolve as an enum instead of a string.

Like this:

```py
removal_policy=RemovalPolicy[props.s3_removal_policy]
```

Comment: thanks, it works, buy why use `[]` ?

Comment: @JackRogers based on the error you're getting, you're providing a string (str) but RemovalPolicy is a type/enum. The underlying SDK isn't smart enough to determine that `"RemovalPolucy.DESTROY"` should map to `RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` so you need to use enum item access to resolve an enum from the provided string.

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes)

Comment: ah interesting, i learn something new today, thank you

Comment: sorry, one more question, how did you know `RemovalPolicy` is a type/enum?

Comment: @JackRogers it's implied by "must be one of (aws_cdk.RemovalPolicy, NoneType); got str". Which essentially says, "must be one of (Type 1, Type 2); got Type 3 instead."